# Which approach would be more efficient to save drag and drop list on server; a constant ajax update vs manual save button?

Tags: php, ajax, performance, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have built a drag and drop form builder for my client using jQuery UI. The form basically has so many items and the client will add, re-order, remove items from the list constantly. I am just having a dilemma with the approach I should take to save the list server-side.

A) Should I just attach the ajax event to update the server whenever the sortable interface is changed. jQuery UI has event for this. But that could mean tens of ajax requests in very short time.

B) Should I just add a button that says "Save changes" and the client uses it whenever he feels happy with the order, click the button and changes are saved on the server. Less neat/pretty than A) but speaking of performance. Do you suggest this solution to be practically better?

I'm thankful for any input as I'm now really unsure which approach to take.

Comment: Should it be possible to edit the list for more than one user at a time?

Comment: @zynth666 No. The editing is done per one user at a time surely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option B) as it would be safer and would produce less overhead. Safer meaning the user wont accidentally safe something they don't want to.

Option C) would be websockets. You could build up a bi-directional connection between client and server that would hold on the whole session the user is editing the list. That would prevent you from sending many requests to the server. A nice PHP library for websockets is Ratchet: http://socketo.me/

Answer (score 0):

Delay moment of ajax request every time when user drags something for a few seconds. That way you will save all changes without forcing user to do 2nd interaction (clicking button) and also you will not send redundant requests. Keep in mind that in that way, you should prevent from closing browser window by the user, you can do that by using **onBeforeUnload**. Of course you could use websockets as mentioned before, but there is some situations where you cannot do that.